# Inherit a class and an interface in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface, c#-to-vb.net

I have a C# code as followed:

```
[Serializable]
public class RoundedHandle : GoRoundedRectangle, IGoHandle {
```

GoRoundedRectangle is a class.
IGoHandle is an interface.

I had tried to convert it to VB .NET code:

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class RoundedHandle
Inherits GoRoundedRectangle, IGoHandle
```

However VB .NET only allows inheritance of one class only.

How can I make the conversion possible by including a class and an interface at the same time?

Thank you.

Comment: `GoRoundedRectangle` is a class and `IGoHandle` is an interface.

Comment: You'll have to use the *Implements* keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vb.net you have to use the keyword **'Implements'** to implement an interface (as shown in the code below):

```vb
<Serializable()>
Public Class RoundedHandle
    Inherits GoRoundedRectangle
    Implements IGoHandle
```